# Why does KMZ refrence FID attribute with Layer.# from GeoSever to Google Earth and how do I change it to reference another attribute?

Tags: geoserver, kmz

I am publishing data to GeoServer, from QGIS, to create network links to display in Google Earth. When I create the a new layer in Google Earth the attribute names of the states are lost. For example, with an imported KMZ into Google Earth, it would be expected to see the name of the states in the red square. However, any data that I reference from the GeoServer, the layers are named state.#. I have looked at other exportable data and it looks to be referencing the FID attribute. Could anyone point me in the right direction as to why this is happening, and how I can figure out how to reference the name attribute? I have searched / read a lot of material but did not find a solution.

[image]